# Will gzip'd files use multiple AU's in DataLake Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

In the EXTRACT documentation there's the (awesome) auto-magic support for gzipped files (which we are using).

But should I assume it won't use more than one AU? As if I understand correctly the files need to be "splitable" to spread across AUs?

Or will it split across AU's once extracted-on-the-fly and / or do gziped files have an index to indicate where they can be split somehow?

Or perhaps I'm muddling the vertex concept with AUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question :).

In general, if the file format is splitable (e.g., basically row-oriented with rows being less than the rowsize limit, which currently is 4MB), then large files will be split into 1GB per vertex.

However, GZip itself is not a splitable format. Thus we cannot split a GZip file during decompression and we end up not splitting the processing of the decompressed file either (the current framework does not provide this). As a consequence, we limit the size of a GZip file to 4GB. If you want scale out with GZip files, we recommend to split the data into several GZip files and then use file sets to scale out processing.

Comment: Great thanks Micheal for the quick response. Do fileset's automagically know if it's gzipped? I'm considering unzipping in data factory to make u-sql perform faster, then rezipping for archiving. It'll be cool if I didn't need to modify the u-sql depending on the input. This might be a new question....

Comment: It may be a new question ;). Currently you can operate on gzipped files in filesets, but currently either all or none of the files have to be gzipped.

Comment: Added a cheeky data factory unzip step (pro's and con's), for our use case it's added nitro to our u-sql so worked a charm, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Watch out for issues where Data Factory fails to unzip the files. This has happened in a few of my use cases.

Comment: Interesting tip thanks @Fastidious, it might explain the odd partially written file, which I'd guess reveals itself as the mystery temp-looking folder.